# weather checking with sys.argv

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I am trying to make a weather search tool using `sys.argv` and just wanted some help. I have the current code

The problem is when I search using the command line I need to type in the country. Is there a way to do it searching only the city?:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import webbrowser
import sys
import pyperclip
import re

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #Get address from command line.
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    address = pyperclip.paste()


webbrowser.open('https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/' + address)
```

command line:

```
./weather.py spain/madrid
./weather.py uk/london
```

Comment: have a dictionary in your code that maps city to country?

Comment: Can you be more specific? _i need to type in the country, is there a way to do it searching only the city_ is a bit unclear/ambiguous.

Comment: Hi! First, it's not easy to find the country from the city name, since you can find the same city in several countries (e.g. Madrid is at least in 4 different countries). In addition to that, you need to get the country name in the same format that timeanddate.com requires it (e.g. is not the same "UK" and "United Kingdom"). Anyway, give a try to geopy (though there are many other APIs which will return city data)

Answer (score 0):

## 1-) Register geonames to use API

- Create a new user account https://www.geonames.org/login
- Activate your account from mail
- On the redirected page after clicking activation link, activate web services

## 2-) Install geocoder

```
pip install geocoder
```

## 3-) Use API

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.geonames('madrid', key='YOURUSERNAMEHERE')
...

webbrowser.open('https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/' + g.country + address)
```

As @Kalma mentioned, `g.country` returns `'United Kingdom'` instead of `'UK'`. You might need to map these values to the ones that timeanddate.com accepts.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, there are probably a number of packages that will do the trick, and likely none of them will work for certain city names. However, geonamescache is very easy to use and will do the trick for unique names. Here is an example (will return "Canada" for "Toronto" as input)

```
pip install geonamescache
```

```
import geonamescache as gnc
gc = gnc.GeonamesCache()
query = 'Toronto'
citykey = list(gc.get_cities_by_name(query)[0])[0]
ccode = gc.get_cities_by_name(query)[0][citykey]['countrycode']
countries = gc.get_countries()
country_name = countries[ccode]['name']
print(country_name)
```